# Positivity property of hermitian inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the inner product $<z,w> = z_{1}\overline{w_{1}} + cz_{1}\overline{w_{2}} + \overline{c}z_{2}\overline{w_{1}} + 9z_{2}\overline{w_{2}}$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$.

I am looking to show that $<z,z> \geq 0$ with equality if and only if $z= 0$.

I have that $<z,z> = |z_{1}|^2 + 9|z_2|^2 + Re[cz_2\overline{z_1}]$ but I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner product will satisfy $\langle z, z \rangle \geq 0$ if and only if $|c| \leq 3$.

**Hint:** Note that
$$
|z_1 + cz_2|^2 = (z_1 + cz_2)\overline{(z_1 + cz_2)} = z_1 \bar z_1 + c z_1 \bar z_2 + \bar c z_2 \bar z_1 + |c|^2 z_2\bar z_2
$$